# List is not rendering rows

Tags: android, listview

i'm implementing a dynamic list that is added to a linearlayout all done by programming.
The problem is that, the rows seem to be inflated (at least the space in the layout is ocupied), but i'm not able to see any of the text that should be contained in this rows.

The first image is from when i don't do "mLayout.addView(mList)"
[image: this image is from when i don't do "mLayout.addView"]

Image with "mLayout.addView(mList)" but without info.

[image: Image with mLayout.addView]

Any idea of what is happening?

EDIT:

Code:

```
    ListView mListView = new ListView(context);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams listLP = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    );
    mListView.setLayoutParams(listLP);
    mListView.setFastScrollAlwaysVisible(true);
    mListView.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
    mListView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
    mListView.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_light));
    mListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_NONE);
    mListView.setItemsCanFocus(false);
    mLinearLayout.addView(mListView);
```

This is the image with the border layouts active.

[image: Border layouts active]

Comment: set layout params to `mList `..

Comment: have you tried enable "Show layout bounds" in developer options? and what mList is ListView, RecyclerView or anything else? Would be great if you can provide some code

Comment: @YatiDumrongsukit added more info to the initial post